# the setting of protecting branch and not allowing develop to push doesn't work in gitlab-ce 8

Tags: gitlab, pull-request

As what i described in the title, the developers still can push code even though the branches on remote server are protected and the option 'develop can push' is not selected. Is there anyone who ever got the same problem before?

Additional info: I setup custom hook with pre-receive and rules works as i expected. I am not sure if it has any impact on the configuration of protected branch and the setting of whether develop can push or not.
version info: GitLab Community Edition 8.9.5

I plan to apply code review in my team, now the plan is blocked by this problem. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the reason that my email address was used administrator. That means I am the master of the project, so i can push the code.